# How can an executable set an environment variable in the parent CMD or batch context?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a Windows console executable (call it SetEnvX.exe) that sets an environment variable. Internally it calls [`SetEnvironmentVariable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686206(v=vs.85).aspx) in the Windows API. That call succeeds.

In the parent CMD instance that executes SetEnvX.exe, the environment variable it created does not exist if `SET` is run right after SetEnvX.exe.

If I create a TEST.CMD with the lines

```
SetEnvX.exe
set
```

the output of the `SET` command within TEST.CMD also does not show the environment variable created by SetEnvX.exe.

How can a program such as SetEnvX.exe create an environment variable that exists for the scope of the interactive CMD shell or batch file from which it was executed? In other words, I do not want to put the environment variable into the global, persistent environment.

Comment: Does SetEnvx.exe create a new environment and then exit that environment, ala SETLOCAL ENDLOCAL?

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible. Whenever you call `SetEnvX.exe` cmd.exe spawns a child process which inherits environment variables from cmd.exe.

`SetEnvX.exe` sets the environment variable in its environment but when it finishes, it's environment block disappears. So parent cmd.exe does not get any variables from child `SetEnvX.exe`.

**TL;DR:**

Child process can inherit parent's environment variables but parent cannot inherit child's environment variables when it exits.

**WORKAROUND:**

If you compiled `SetEnvX.exe` by yourself, instead of setting up environment variable, you can print the value and then capture it in cmd.exe. E.g.:

```
for /f "delims=" %%k in ('SetEnvX.exe') do set VARIABLE=%%k
```

Comment: Technically it's possible (sometimes) to open the parent process and rewrite its environment block, but it's not advisable and a poor design. You need a cooperative design like your workaround that writes the new variables to stdout.

Comment: Note that environment variables are Unicode and `for /f` decodes line by line read from the pipe using the console's current output codepage. In general, you may need to cooperate a bit more by setting the console to codepage 65001 (UTF-8) and having SetEnvX.exe write UTF-8 to stdout.

Comment: `cmd /k "set a=b"` in you cmd file will set `a` to the current command line when returns.

Answer (score 1):

Each process inherits the variables of its parents, at birth. You can't inherit variables from a child. And while there's a "global persistent environment" in the registry, that is *not* the environment in a random CMD.EXE process.

Note that batch files are executed by CMD.EXE and generally do not have their own process.

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows 7 I was able to accomplish this for batch utilities that were intended to set environment variables for the process in which they were executing (parent process) by using DLL injection into the parent process.  However, all of my batch utilities that used this technique broke in Windows 10.  Using the for command and writing set commands to batch files aren't always solutions because sometimes the desired environment variable contents is output of another command that is unpredictable in advance and has command line quoting issues that are extremely difficult (impossible?) to program around.  A better technique is badly needed because the built in set and for commands are extremely limiting.  Some of this was much better in Windows XP and prior versions because you could actually pipe output from a command directly into the SET command.  However, Microsoft, in their infinite wisdom (NOT!) chose to remove that capability in Windows 7 and later (not sure about Vista).