# Using Win32::Env perl module, environment variable not setting permanently in windows

Tags: perl

`Win32::Env` module is used for environment variable set for temporary basis.
I need to set permanently, please help

Please help me to set as permanent .
Because i want it use in another exe.

```
use Win32::Env;

SetEnv(ENV_USER, 'AUTO_EXCEL_EXPORT', 'TRUE');
```

By this code, i can set environment variable in windows only as temporary.
when i check with echo command of that variable it is not showing.
because it is set as semi permanent value.

Comment: Does assigning to %ENV ie `$ENV{AUTO_EXCEL_EXPORT} = 'TRUE'` solve the problem?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573817/where-are-environment-variables-stored-in-registry) is a question, that discusses where environment variables are (permanently) stored in the registry. You could add it there.

Comment: %ENV ie $ENV{AUTO_EXCEL_EXPORT} = 'TRUE'
not working , it is not setting in my pc

it is setting as locally for perl consolse alone.

not even for this command echo %AUTO_EXCEL_EXPORT%
it shows %AUTO_EXCEL_EXPORT%

Comment: The environment is private to each process. You can spawn a new command window from inside the perl script, and it will default to a copy of the parent's process (which has the modified environment).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can an executable set an environment variable in the parent CMD or batch context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46246163/how-can-an-executable-set-an-environment-variable-in-the-parent-cmd-or-batch-con)

Answer (score 2):

When assigning/changing environment variables in Windows, the Explorer subsystem needs to be notified that the changes occurred before newly opened windows/applications see the changes. If this doesn't happen, then a reboot is necessary before other processes will see the changes.

As you can see in the [SYNOPSIS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::Env#SYNOPSIS) of [Win32::Env](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::Env), they've got a call to [BroadcastEnv()](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::Env#BroadcastEnv()) which performs said notification task.

After reviewing the module's code, the author is setting the variables within the registry, so that call should correct the issue. Note though, that if you're running things from a `cmd` window while running your script, no matter what, you have to close that window and open a new one for the changes to take effect. All new windows should get the updated environment.

Example:

```
use Win32::Env;

SetEnv(ENV_USER, 'AUTO_EXCEL_EXPORT', 'TRUE');

BroadcastEnv();
```

Comment: Any idea to get ENV change in same session ??

Comment: @AmarendhiranAmar For all intents and purposes, you can't unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

```
 use Win32::Env; 
SetEnv(ENV_USER, 'AUTO_EXCEL_EXPORT', 'FALSE');
BroadcastEnv();
print "\n";
DelEnv(ENV_USER, 'AUTO_EXCEL_EXPORT');
print "\n";
SetEnv(ENV_USER, 'AUTO_EXCEL_EXPORT', 'TRUE');
BroadcastEnv();
```

if i run this code its setting only first ENV  ( false ) value, in echo command why??????

Comment: Please reply for this