# Change current working directory of the terminal in Python

Tags: python

First of all, I am aware of the `os.chdir()` function and unfortunately it's not what I need.

I have a Python script that does stuff, including creating a folder `new_folder`. I am running this script from a terminal (it is added to the PATH)

```
C:\users\me\Desktop> my_script
```

and I want it to change the current working directory of my terminal, like this:

```
C:\users\me\Desktop> my_script
C:\users\me\Desktop\new_folder>
```

Is this even possible? And if so, how can I do it?

Comment: Not possible. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46246163/how-can-an-executable-set-an-environment-variable-in-the-parent-cmd-or-batch-con) is about a program changing environment variables but the reasoning is the same: a child process cannot affect the environment of the parent process.

Comment: Your CMD/Powershell process is different from the one spawned with `[python] my_script`

Comment: Why do you need to do so? If you want to execute a bash script after that you can use python to do so at the specified directory. Maybe you don't need to do this?

Comment: not sure if it's a valid solution, but if you create a batch script that calls the python script, which will return the directory, and then you `cd` to that directory, and you call that batch script with `call script.bat` that might work. It's a very roundabout and hacky way to do that and as was mentioned above you can probably avoid it by better defining your issue and solving it the correct way. if you add more details on your problem you might get a better answer here.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in my comment, this is a very roundabout hacky way of doing it, and is probably a bad solution to your issue. that said, this is how it could be done:

if you use a batch file that calls a python script, that script would output the directory you wish to cd into:

example python script:

```
print("c:\your\directory")
```

example batch script:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('C:\Path\To\python\python.exe your_python_script.py') do cd "%%i"
```

running this batch script yields:

```
c:\dir1>batchscript.bat
c:\dir1>for /f "delims=" %i in ('C:\Path\To\python\python.exe your_python_script.py') do cd "%i"
c:\dir1>cd "c:\dir2"
c:\dir2>
```

Notice we moved from dir1 to dir2 which is what I put in the output of my python script.

This will only work if your python script doesn't output anything other than the directory.

Again: not a good solution, but a solution.