# How to modify the env in the bat script to take effect to the current process in Rust

Tags: batch-file, rust, environment-variables

After I execute a bat script in rust, how to make the `set env1=value1` in the bat script take effect to the current process.

some.bat

```
do other...
set env1=value1
do other...
```

in rust

```rust
//change env in batch script.
Command::new("cmd")
            .args(["/C", "some.bat"])
            .status()
            .expect("failed to execute process");

//read env in current process.
let key = "env1";
match env::var(key) {
    Ok(val) => println!("{key}: {val:?}"),
    Err(e) => println!("couldn't interpret {key}: {e}"),
}
```

Comment: At least in Linux, setting parent process env variable from a child is not possible. Possibly same in windows as well? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46246163/how-can-an-executable-set-an-environment-variable-in-the-parent-cmd-or-batch-con

Comment: Variables set in a batch script do not back-propagate into the calling process. Consider using a standardized form like [`dotenv`](https://docs.rs/dotenv/latest/dotenv/) to communicate variables to other processes.

Comment: The simplest solution is to split your Rust program in two parts: the first one start some.bat and that is it. Then, modify some.bat so the last command run the second part in rust. In this way, the second part _can_ access the variables set in some.bat

Comment: Thank you for your enthusiastic answers, I understand, I know what to do;